# How to map string with date-time pattern into typescript Date object

Tags: .net, typescript, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

I use openapi-generator to obtain auto generated TypeScript code.
Property declared in c# in background as DateTime appears in swagger.sjon as

```
"type": "string", "format": "date-time"
```

As I know generation could be fired with parameter

> --type-mapping=string=Date

then all of strings become a Date objects. My question is how to run generation to change all properties with type string and format equal to date-time onto Date object in TypeScript and don't change other string's properties?